# Are DevOps related questions about Software Escrow on-topic (or not)?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Software Escrow (SE) is about getting a 3rd party involved, trusted by 2 parties, where pieces of software components (Artefacts?) get deposited, with al sorts of "strings attached".

If you know a bit about SCM (Software Change Management), then you'll understand (as I like to explain it) it's a special kind of SCM. But because of its nature, all sorts of extra challenges show up. Think of a legal person, such as a lawyer, acting as a release manager (not knnowing at all what the software application is supposed to do) ... fun garanteed!

So is SE on-topic or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for any pay only software, with some luck someone with enough expertise may be able to answer your question.

As long as the question describe a real problem with enough details and background I see no reason to bring them off topic, but therés a good chance you won't get an answer as the question about got smudge and ansible vault [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/106/git-clean-smudge-filters-for-ansible-vault-secrets).

Main difference is that ansible is free, someone willing to tackle the problem can install, test and'maybe answer.

Comment: Hm, I didn't think about yes/or no having to pay for software But how about a variation like a "Saas"-system, where if my business depends on such system, and the Saas-vendor disappears? Actually there you are already with a first question: how do you handle such situation in the context of SE (what kind of solution would one recommend)? PS: and now time for a walk ... really ... it's urgent ...

Comment: I just mean that when you ask about licensed software, no one interested but not having a license can answer, thus reducing the chances to get an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Depositing to a Software Escrow is fundamentally just another variation of a delivery in the software development process. Which can considered for automation.

I'd definitely consider it on-topic for DevOps.